# Can I use set notation that accounts for multiplicity?

Tags: linear-algebra, elementary-set-theory, notation, multisets

Can I use $\{\lambda_i,\mu_i\}$ to describe a matrix's eigenvalues and account for their multiplicity?

Here $\lambda_i$ would be the eigenvalues, and $\mu_i$ would be its multiplicity.

(I need the multiplicity of the eigenvalues in my work, in set notation, but don't want to use the notation such as $\{1,1,1,2,3,3,4,4,4,4\}$.)

Comment: What do you want to do next? That is what for do you need this notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not appropriate since sets are inherently unordered. You could use an ordered pair $(\lambda_i,\mu_i)$. Since you have a list of eigenvalues with their multiplicity, a set of ordered pairs

$$\left\{(\lambda_1,\mu_1),(\lambda_2,\mu_2), \dotsc, (\lambda_n,\mu_n)\right\}
$$

would probably be best.

Comment: But couldn't I just use $\{\lambda_i, \mu_i \}$?

Comment: @user58865 no you cannot. As $\{2,3\} =\{3,2\} $ and you can hardly be indifferent to a having EV 2 with mult 3 or EV 3 with mult 2.

Comment: Ah, good point @quid - thanks...

Answer (score 1):

You're sort of after a "multiset".  (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiset.)  The typical notation for $\{2,2,2,5,5\}$ would be $\{(2,3),(5,2)\}.$  Since $\{*\}$ is used for un-ordered pairs and $(*)$ for ordered pairs, then the parens would be more appropriate.

Comment: I don't need ordering of the eigenvalues, actually...and regarding eigenvalues, I wonder whether set notation is more appropriate than list notation...

Comment: The ordering is because the first element of your pair is the eigenvalue and the second element is the multiplicity.  If you use braces, convention is that $\{3,1\} = \{1,3\}$, but in your proposed notation they mean different things.  So order matters.

Answer (score 1):

You could also consider a *family*, which takes account for multiplicity:

$$(2,2,2,5,5)$$

but it also takes account for order, so may be it is not what you're looking for?

Comment: Right, I don't need ordering...